# SQL Query to group by or filter result set

Tags: sql, filter, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this...

```
Name   | Clause
---------------
TableA  Dependency1
TableA  Dependency2
TableA  Dependency3
TableB  Dependency1
TableB  Dependency2
...................
```

and want to filter or group it so it looks like this:

```
Name   | Clause
---------------
TableA  Dependency1
        Dependency2
        Dependency3
TableB  Dependency1
        Dependency2
...................
```

What would be the SQL query for this?

Comment: That's not how SQL works.  The second example you've posted is intrinsically identical to the first, and merely changes the output rendering.  You wouldn't do that with SQL, but with whatever application you're presenting your data in.

Comment: You could query that original table and use an actual display technology (in a webpage, paste it into an excel document, etc).  But doing layout/display using a SQL query doesn't make sense.

Comment: @user1161318 - 1) There's no GROUP_CONCAT in SQL Server, and 2) that's not what he's asking for - note that line breaks in his output represent new rows rather than \n.

Comment: @TheSmose called this one, baaaaad idea. Think it would have to be a cursor with that data anyway, slow unwieldy unmaintainable and truly trivial to achieve with any sort of reporting application.

Comment: Comment deleted.  I keep forgetting about the SQL flavors!